Ordinary substitution really corresponds to de Bruijn's substitution
The proof (Coq, 1600 lines) 
https://www.mediafire.com/file/kxhk8yo50yq6amo/99.v/file 
(Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 32761.) 
Is the result new? 
P.S.Substitution for de Bruijn terms is defined in a completely different way than the ordinary substitution. As far as I know, no one has ever proven their correspondence. For good reason, it's very difficult. I think I've proven it. All definitions are given at the beginning (you need to know the basics of explicit substitution calculus, I recommend reading a couple of articles by Pierre Lescanne). The topic is practically important for proof checking. 
P.P.S.And I didn't demand to understand the proof, I asked "Is the result new?" Sorry. 
P.P.P.S.Summary of the first 200 lines

Definitions of lambda-terms and de Bruijn terms;
Standard definition of the 'transfer' function 
transfer (Gamma, M) 
this function takes a list of variables (context) Gamma, a lambda-term M and produces a de Bruijn term;
Definitions of simultaneous substitution 
M [N0/x0,...,Nk/xk] 
and similar de Bruijn substitution 
M' [N'0,...,N'k] 
(the last definition may be my own, but not very strange) ;
Statement of the main theorem 
forall context Gamma, lambda-term M and substitution [N0/x0,...,Nk/xk]
if the list x0,...,xk does not contain repetitions then 
transfer (Gamma, M [N0/x0,...,Nk/xk]) = M'[N'0,...,N'k] 
where 
M' = transfer ([x0,...,xk]++Gamma, M) 
N'0 = transfer (Gamma, N0) 
... 
N'k = transfer (Gamma, Nk)


With a "question" like this, how do I even know that link isn't some kind of virus.  Voting to close...

For the case that this is a well-intentioned question, I've seen many outsiders to math and CS assume if they post a result, the community will instantly understand its significance. (They have heard too many stories of zero-word lectures or one-paragraph papers, i.e. a mathematical mic drop.) In my experience, even a good result needs to be motivated for experts to understand its significance. Since PA.SX isn't for posting results, if you have a legitimate question such as if results like this are new and formalized before, then ask a motivated question. (Also use GitHub for code.)

@JasonRute At least you don't vote anonymously.

You can improve the question by briefly describing your code, what it tries to achieve and by what method. @JasonRute I looked at the code and it's probably not a virus, formalizing some well-scoped syntax, so it's not off topic like proving the Riemann hypothesis would be.

@Trebor As far as I know, no one has ever proven the correspondence of these things. For good reason, it's very difficult.  The method is "By thinking about it all the time." There is no single main idea, the proof is combinatorially complex.

"It's all there in the code" is not helpful if you want people to actually try to read and understand you. You need to summarize in natural language and provide context for what you're doing.

@Trebor I know. I tried.  At least they will know that I really proved something. If there was a simple proof, de Bruijn would have found it.

@Trebor I'm sorry, where do the difficulties begin? For example, is it clear what \Uparrow and \uparrow are? I will write a more understandable article, but not right now (tired of 1600 lines).

The difficulty is that as a general fact, people do not read 1600 lines of code unless they are given a good reason to. You need to give the reason by providing context.

You are still not saying what the result is! What are "these things"? There are by now a million ways of defining "ordinary" substitution and substitution for de Bruijn terms (and even that is ambiguous). Can you at least provide us with precise definitions of what you mean by that (which should be able to fit in a SE question).

@MevenLennon-Bertrand I gave all the definitions and the formulation of the main theorem at the very beginning (no need to read 1600 lines)

Your strategy is to not humor us after several requests to give a brief summary. What should be the strategy of those who are attempting to help you (I count three people so far)?

P.S. I amended my answer with further references that are relevant.

Let me be a bit more constructive here. A summary would contain the following information: which specific definitions "at the beginning of the file" are the most important one, and for each one a very short description in English; where is the main theorem, and a short description in English on what it states. One would expect that by reading the main definitions, the main theorem becomes udnerstandable. Do you think you can provide those?

@AndrejBauer I did.

@MevenLennon-Bertrand I tried to improve.

@Trebor I tried to improve.

I think what AB asked for is high-level ideas, and you refused to phrase your main theorem like that, instead you just rewrote it using Coq-like wording. I don't think that's helpful. Do you really want people to understand what you did? Also, your code cannot be viewed without downloading them first, and you choose to do nothing to that. I'm closing this with the hope of a better-quality version of it could be re-asked.

It is hard to tell what is in those 1600 of code, especially with so few comments, but regarding substitution in $\lambda$-calculus with concrete names, you could have a look at Phil Wadler's Programming Language Foundations in Agda. In particular, the chapter Lambda: Introduction to Lambda Calculus has a section on substitution with concrete names. Later on there is also a treatment of de Bruijn indices.
I am not saying PFLA covers what you did. I do not know what you did, but it seems clear that PLFA might be a useful reference.
Another resource is to look at the POPLMark challenge and POPLMark reloaded, where you will find a host of formalizations of substitution, done in various ways, although I think they don't compare them to each other formally. It should still be useful to familiarize yourself with all the approaches people have taken, and to learn from their experience.
Another paper that seems relevant is A Head-to-Head Comparison of de Bruijn Indices and Names. Once again, they don't prove theorems showing any sort of equivalence. Howevever, it would be worth digging a bit more, I would expect it that some people must have worked on it before.
